# SystemVerilog: Need to change 2 bits in very large array

Tags: arrays, indexing, system-verilog

I have an array of size 2400. I want to be able to update a certain bit in this array based on combinational logic that determines the index of that bit.

Accessing the bit directly gives me a multiple driver error due to having already assigning the array an initial value, and after trying to implement a state machine, I have found it nearly impossible due to it requiring the previous value of the entire array. ie: Can't assign ranges with a variable.

```
logic [0:2400] big_array;
assign big_array = {ALL BITS ASSIGNED};
//Here is where I want to be able to update
logic [11:0] index;
//INDEX Determined via logic
assign big_array[index] = 1'b0;
```

Any help would be awesome!

Note: I'm fairly sure I can accomplish this through some type of state machine because I am assigning an original value, but I can't figure it out. Is it possible to priority assign values?

Subtracting is out of the questions since the number would be too large.

Comment: Remove all `assign` statements. Use `for` loop in `always @(*)` to assign values to all variables. Whenever `i==index` (`i` is loop iterator), then assign `1'b0` at that index.

Comment: @sharvil111 SystemVerilog should use `always_comb` instead of `always @(*)`

Comment: @Greg Oh ya, time zero event and enhanced sensitivity for functions. `always_comb` is good. Thanks.

Comment: @sharvil111 Thanks for the help. I think I'm getting closer. Now I have   `always_comb  
begin  
 original = {//2400 bits here};  
for(int i=0; i<2400; i++)begin  
   if(i==index) begin  
    big_array[i] = 1'b0;  
   end  
   else begin  
    big_array[i] = original[i];  
   end  
 end  
end`  
And it seems like it registers the change for a moment, but then goes back to the original instead of staying?

Comment: @mruben09 is the expression `original = {//2400 bits here};` used to set the initial value of `original`? If so, then this value is set each time the always block is executed. Can you elaborate this part of code?

Comment: @sharvil111 Yes. These are the values I want the array to start with. After that, I want to be able to turn off values in the array based on a index that is calculated. This index would continuously change, until all bits are off.

Comment: Note, you can simplify this as you have a vector (instead of an unpacked array). `always_comb begin big_array = { STUFF }; big_array[index] = 1'b0; end` If you dont have some kind of register or delay between changes to `index` it will not work. Also note that `big_array` will NOT retain its value in this form. If you want to store the value of `big_array` so it changes over a period of time, youll need to implement a register to store the value: `always_ff @(posedge clk, posedge rst) begin if (rst) big_array <= { STUFF }; else big_array[index] <= 1'b0; end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but there is an array (vector) of 2400 bits.  Given an index, which we'll assume you derived using combinational logic as you said, the element at that index is updated.

I am giving a solution that is meant for synthesizable RTL, since you used the word *combinational*, and I am assuming you are trying to synthesize this logic to hardware.

```
logic [2399:0] big_array;
logic [11:0]   index;

always_comb begin
   // combinational logic here
   index = ...
end

always_ff @(posedge clk, posedge reset) begin
   if (reset) begin
      big_array = '0;    // vector fill operation
   end else begin
      big_array[index] = ...;
   end
end
```

I haven't checked the code above for syntax errors.  Also, note that I used a clocked process for the array updating, however, you could use some other triggering mechanism if you weren't intending to synthesize this code.
Likewise, you could use an initial statement instead of the reset block.

I think the assignment `big_array[index] = ...` will elaborate, but if not you could loop through all indices until a match is found as other commenters have suggested.